# how to add markers and center map in signup form django-map-widget

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, maps, google-maps-markers, django-widget

Using [django-map-widget](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets) to render a map widget in forms. it works fine, but...

I want to trigger the map in two ways (dynamically via javascript):

1. trigger to re-center map on x,y
2. trigger to add a marker to map on x,y

I tried so many ways, but i can't solve it.

You can [see and play with my form here](https://billigerobotter.dk/signup/)

Here are one of my attempts:

```
var locationRio = {lat: -22.915, lng: -43.197};
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: locationRio,
  map: $("#location-map-elem").map,
  title: 'Hello World!'
});
```

I am 90% sure my error is this part: **$("#location-map-elem").map**

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to access google map object for this. The accessing map object feature doesn't release yet. So, you need to install [django-map-widgets](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets) directly from the master branch.

`pip install git+git://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets.git@master`

Check this [pull-request](https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/pull/48) for more info.

After you installed the latest version, you will able to play with the Google Map JS API.

```js
// re-center your marker 
var map = $('your-map-element').data(map);
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(your_marker.getPosition());
map.fitBounds(bounds);
```

Comment: i tried this:

var map = $('#location-map-elem').data(map);
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: 57.0230, lng: 10.087},
    map: map,
    draggable: true
});
var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
bounds.extend(marker.getPosition());
map.fitBounds(bounds);

i get these errors:
InvalidValueError: setMap: not an instance of Map; and not an instance of StreetViewPanorama
Uncaught TypeError: map.fitBounds is not a function

Comment: That snippet code could be wrong, did you check google map JS documentation for re-centring? 

As I know, you should able to re-center the map after you got the `map` JS instance.

Comment: @MichaelLind I tested the code snippet and it worked for me, check the Google Map documentation.

Comment: https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/blob/18e0d592ae7afea9aadadbb30d383bdd573b2de8/mapwidgets/static/mapwidgets/js/mw_google_point_field.js#L53

https://github.com/erdem/django-map-widgets/blob/18e0d592ae7afea9aadadbb30d383bdd573b2de8/mapwidgets/static/mapwidgets/js/mw_google_point_field.js#L79

These methods could be an example for your case. Check the these and implement with your `map` object instead of `this.map`. Thanks

Comment: thank you. but problem is that map is undefined. var map = $('your-map-element').data(map); for me it makes no sense, cause map, in the sentences, is undefined. maybe im blind or stupid, sorry, but i still cant see how this can be done. im giving up. moving on with another widget

Comment: @MichaelLind this selector works for me: var map = $('.mw-map').data('map');